# Call to undefined function testinput() line 48

Tags: php, mysql, function, post, mysqli

```
<script>
    function testinput(value) {
        value = trim(value);
        value = stripslashes(value);
        value = htmlspecialchars(value);
    }
</script>

<?php
    $servername ="localhost";
    $username = "k";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "password";

    $connect1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


    if($connect1->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed:  " . $connnect1->connect_error);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['btnreg'])) {
        $klantVoornaam = $_POST["txtVoornaam"];
        $klantAchternaam = $_POST["txtAchternaam"];
        $klantMail = $_POST["txtEmail"];
        $klantWachtwoord = $_POST["txtWw"];

        (line48)$klantVoornaam = testinput($klantVoornaam);
        $klantAchternaam = testinput($klantAchternaam);
        $klantMail = testinput($klantMail);
        $klantWachtwoord = testinput($klantWachtwoord);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `klanten` (KlantID, Voornaam, Achternaam, Wachtwoord, Email, Klantreg, KlantActief) 
        VALUES(NULL,'".$klantVoornaam."','".$klantAchternaam."', '".md5($klantWachtwoord)."','".$klantMail."',". regCode() ."','0')";

        $qresult = mysql_query($sql);


        if($connect1 ->query($qresult)){

            echo "Registered successfully!";
            echo "Voornaam: " . $klantVoornaam;
            echo "Achternaam" . $klantAchternaam;
            echo "E-mail" . $klantMail;
            echo "Wachtwoord" . $klantWachtwoord;

        }
    }
?>
```

Basically says the function `testinput()` I made above is `undefined` but I doesn't seem to see the mistake in that.
The script is set in my body as is the rest, using `testinput()` to strip of any strange characters since it's a username.

Comment: Which language is `testinput()` supposed to be?  PHP (`<?php`) or JavaScript (`<script>`)?

Comment: remove all the code inside script tags, make the function in php not js

Comment: `mysqli` doesn't work with `mysql_`. Use prepared statements as well, you are using a driver that supports them. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php Also if `$klantWachtwoord` you should consider a new hashing mechanics and not alter it, that could decrease the security of it.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `testinput` in javascript, you can't call it from PHP. Instead, you should define it in PHP:

```
<?php

function testinput($value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    $value = stripslashes($value);
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    return $value;
}

// Rest of your PHP code
```

BTW: This function doesn't really test your input, it sanitizes it. You should probably give it a different name to better describe what it does.

Comment: And it doesn't really do a good job of sanitizing it either.  `stripslashes` is the *opposite* of what you want and `htmlspecialchars` is *only* for displaying it on your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Thx alot! Stupid mistake by me, the teacher told me to use these trim/strips so I thought I'd stick with it